# sql stored procedureExecution Timeout Expired.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have couple of stored procedures in our sql server 2008 that gets executed one after another, im facing a sql error (Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding) at the last one which updates or inserts against a 1 million records table while it works with smaller files but when updating or inserting this number of records it stops and throws that error , how can i tune the stored procedure, i tried to clean the server with sp_updatestates but no luck, i'd appreciate any help, thank you, here is my stored procedure code :

```
    USE [DBTest]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateData]

    @ItemsExt dbo.TT_ItemsExt READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    Declare 
        @ItemID nvarchar(36)
    ,@DescE nvarchar(50)
    ,etc 
    ,etc
    --------------------------------------- 

    DECLARE Item_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        ItemID
    ,DescE
    ,etc
    ,etc
    FROM @ItemsExt

    OPEN Item_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM Item_cursor INTO
        @ItemID
    ,@DescE
    ,etc
    ,etc

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


        If exists (select * from Items WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)
        Begin 

            Update dbo.Items SET
            DescEng = @DescE
            ,etc = @etc
            WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
        End
        ElSE
        Begin

            Declare @ItemNumber nvarChar(36)
            SET @ItemNumber = REPLACE((REPLACE(RIGHT(@ItemID, LEN(@ItemID) - 1))

            insert into dbo.Items 
             (ItemID    ,  etc)

            VALUES (@ItemID, etc)
        End

        --ItemsReplacment Table
        If exists (select * from dbo.ItemsReplacement WHERE ItemID = @ItemID)
        Begin 

            Update dbo.ItemsReplacement SET

            ItemAlter= @AlternativeItem
            ,etc
            WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
        End
        ElSE
        Begin

            Insert Into dbo.ItemsReplacement Values (
            @ItemID
            ,etc
            ,etc)
        End

        FETCH NEXT FROM Item_cursor INTO
        @ItemID
        ,@DescE
        ,etc
        ,etc
    END 
    CLOSE Item_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE Item_cursor;

END
```

ps: the timeout of execution is set to 0 meaning infinite.

Comment: That's way too broad a question to ask.  You need to narrow down the issue to which part of the procedure is taking the most time, then make sure you have proper indexes on tables, etc.  One thing that stands out though is that you are looping over a cursor and doing row by row updates.  That's slow.  Think about if it's possible to use a single SQL statement instead of a loop.

Comment: First of all you should really try to get rid of cursors-loop. While Oracle can handle that with no problem, my experience with SQL Server tells me that whenever possible change cursor loops into statements (even if they will be complex ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better aproach to those updates and inserts:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateData]

@ItemsExt dbo.TT_ItemsExt READONLY
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE IT
  SET
    DescEng = ITE.DescE,
    etc = ITE.etc
  FROM 
    dbo.Items IT
    INNER JOIN ItemsExt ITE ON (IT.ItemID = ITE.ItemID);

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.Items
  (
    ItemID,
    etc
  ) 
  SELECT
      ITE.ItemID, 
      ITE.etc
    FROM 
      dbo.ItemsExt ITE;
    WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Items WHERE ItemID = ITE.ItemID);

UPDATE ITR
  SET
    ItemAlt = 0, --AlternativeItem?
    etc = ITE.etc
  FROM  
    dbo.ItemsReplacement ITR
    INNER JOIN ItemsExt ITE ON (ITR.ItemID = ITE.ItemID);

INSERT INTO 
    dbo.ItemsReplacement
  (
    ItemID,
    etc
  )
  SELECT
      ITE.ItemID, 
      ITE.etc
    FROM 
      dbo.ItemsExt ITE;
    WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ItemsReplacement WHERE ItemID = ITE.ItemID);  

END
```

That way you avoid unecessary cursor-loops and let the Database do it's magic on planning the execution.

And by the way: Shouldn't it have any kind of "restriction" on those updates and inserts? Are you planning on run all those tables on all executions?

!! On your original code you were using `@AlternativeItem` that I couldn't find anywhere. Used `0` in my response.

Comment: thank you all, @Marcelo Mayara i will try that it sounds promising, as for your question : "Shouldn't it have any kind of "restriction" on those updates and inserts? Are you planning on run all those tables on all executions?" this sp is actually based on another one which handles restrictions so no worries, i'm having trouble with the logic only, as for AlternativeItem it's okay too the syntax is not important i just took a stub off my sp to show how it works in general, and i believe your help seems promising i will try it, thank you very much .

Comment: Marcelo, i tweaked your approach just a lil bit and it worked like a charm with no timeout or anything, thank you very much for your help.